# Is it possible/feasible to limit website access to a geographic area?

Tags: web

I'm interested in building a very simple website that would allow users within a certain distance of a geographic point to login and post to a message board.  Is limiting access to a website by IP ranges a reasonable means of accomplishing a task like this?  If not, is there another means that exists?

Comment: There is no reliable way. Mobile users' IPs, for example, usually won't give you reliable location data; so will many "normal" DSL IPs. There's client side geolocation but that can be disabled, and of course very easily faked.

Comment: While it is sort of feasible it is also nearly impossible. Consider things like a person connected to a WAN. Their broadcast IP may appear to in one location but their actual physical location is somewhere completely different. For example, we have users all over the globe at our company. When using their IP to "locate" them they all appear to be at our corporate headquarters. Then consider mobile users and it just becomes way too ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geoblocking, which is what you are asking about, is usually performed using databases of IPs by city, like this one: https://db-ip.com/

There are ways around this, however. Most commonly, using a vpn or proxy to channel requests through a different IP address.